# Cannot get my bullet list to display correctly

Tags: css, image, list

I am using a small application that includes a bullet list of countries and flags. The list was originally using the regular bullet icons, but I wanted to include flags too. There are 2 areas in the application that affect the list, the first is an index.php file (which is where I changed the code to select the flag images. The entire content of that file is as follows:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("li").click(function() {
    parent.addLanguageCode();
    var b = $('.arrowchat_trayclick').attr('id');
    b = b.substr('30');

    var info = $(this).attr('id');
    if (info != b) {
      $('.goog-te-combo', top.document).val(info);
      parent.changeLanguage();

      $('#arrowchat_applications_button_' + b).click();
      $('#arrowchat_applications_button_' + b + ' img').attr('src', '{$base_url}images/' + info + '.png');
      $('#arrowchat_app_link_' + b + ' img').attr('src', '{$base_url}images/' + info + '.png');
      $.cookie('arrowchat_language_app', info);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {}

.small {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.translate_ul ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.translate_ul li {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  width: 102px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-position: 0 -1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0 0 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.translate_container {
  background-color: #fffff;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.translate_container a {
  color: #11648F;
}

.translating {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!--

<?php  #PHP bits from the op, left here but useless for a snippet

 require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/config.php");

 // Gets the folder path without filename
 function GetFileDir($php_self) { 
  $filename2 = "";
  $filename = explode("/", $php_self);
  for( $i = 0; $i < (count($filename) - 1); ++$i ) { 
   $filename2 .= $filename[$i].'/'; 
  } 
  return $filename2; 
 } 

 $base_url = GetFileDir($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

echo <<<EOD
-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>

  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="{$base_url}includes/css/style.css" />

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{$base_url}includes/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="{$base_url}includes/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div style="width:100%;margin:0 auto;margin-top: 0px;height:300px" class="translate_ul">

    <div class="translate_container" style="height:300px;">

      <ul class="languages" style="height: 300px;">
        <li id="af"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/af.png" alt="af" />Afrikaans</li>
        <li id="sq"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sq.png" alt="sq" />Albanian</li>
        <li id="ar"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ar.png" alt="ar" />Arabic</li>
        <li id="be"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/be.png" alt="be" />Belarusian</li>
        <li id="bg"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/bg.png" alt="bg" />Bulgarian</li>
        <li id="ca"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ca.png" alt="ca" />Catalan</li>
        <li id="zh-CN"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/zh-CN.png" alt="zh-CN" />Chinese (Simple)</li>
        <li id="zh-TW"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/zh-TW.png" alt="zh-TW" />Chinese (Traditional)</li>
        <li id="hr"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/hr.png" alt="hr" />Croatian</li>
        <li id="cs"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/cs.png" alt="cs" />Czech</li>
        <li id="da"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/da.png" alt="da" />Danish</li>
        <li id="nl"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/nl.png" alt="nl" />Dutch</li>
        <li id="en"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/en.png" alt="en" />English</li>
        <li id="et"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/et.png" alt="et" />Estonian</li>
        <li id="tl"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/tl.png" alt="tl" />Filipino</li>
        <li id="fi"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/fi.png" alt="fi" />Finnish</li>
        <li id="fr"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/fr.png" alt="fr" />French</li>
        <li id="gl"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/gl.png" alt="gl" />Galician</li>
        <li id="de"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/de.png" alt="de" />German</li>
        <li id="el"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/el.png" alt="el" />Greek</li>
        <li id="ht"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ht.png" alt="ht" />Haitian Creole</li>
        <li id="iw"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/iw.png" alt="iw" />Hebrew</li>
        <li id="hi"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/hi.png" alt="hi" />Hindi</li>
        <li id="hu"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/hu.png" alt="hu" />Hungarian</li>
        <li id="is"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/is.png" alt="is" />Icelandic</li>
        <li id="id"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/id.png" alt="id" />Indonesian</li>
        <li id="ga"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ga.png" alt="ga" />Irish</li>
        <li id="it"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/it.png" alt="it" />Italian</li>
        <li id="ja"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ja.png" alt="ja" />Japanese</li>
        <li id="ko"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ko.png" alt="ko" />Korean</li>
        <li id="lv"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/lv.png" alt="lv" />Latvian</li>
        <li id="lt"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/lt.png" alt="lt" />Lithuanian</li>
        <li id="mk"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/mk.png" alt="mk" />Macedonian</li>
        <li id="ms"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ms.png" alt="ms" />Malay</li>
        <li id="mt"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/mt.png" alt="mt" />Maltese</li>
        <li id="no"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/no.png" alt="no" />Norwegian</li>
        <li id="fa"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/fa.png" alt="fa" />Persian</li>
        <li id="pl"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/pl.png" alt="pl" />Polish</li>
        <li id="pt"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/pt.png" alt="pt" />Portuguese</li>
        <li id="ro"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ro.png" alt="ro" />Romanian</li>
        <li id="ru"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/ru.png" alt="ru" />Russian</li>
        <li id="sr"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sr.png" alt="sr" />Serbian</li>
        <li id="sk"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sk.png" alt="sk" />Slovak</li>
        <li id="sl"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sl.png" alt="sl" />Slovenian</li>
        <li id="es"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/es.png" alt="es" />Spanish</li>
        <li id="sw"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sw.png" alt="sw" />Swahili</li>
        <li id="sv"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/sv.png" alt="sv" />Swedish</li>
        <li id="th"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/th.png" alt="th" />Thai</li>
        <li id="tr"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/tr.png" alt="tr" />Turkish</li>
        <li id="uk"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/uk.png" alt="uk" />Ukrainian</li>
        <li id="vi"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/vi.png" alt="vi" />Vietnamese</li>
        <li id="cy"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/cy.png" alt="cy" />Welsh</li>
        <li id="yi"><img src="/arrowchat/applications/translate/images/yi.png" alt="yi" />Yiddish</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="translating">
        {$translate_language[0]}
      </div>

      <div style="clear:both"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Then there is a css file which I have been messing with for hours but without success:

My list output looks like the attached image

[how list currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JATp1.png)

All I want to do is make the country names sit to the right of the flags, but nothing I have tried so far has managed to achieve this.

Can anyone help me?

Kind regards

Comment: maybe you should set a shorter & working snippet with fake image

Comment: Can you upload your code to something like plunkr? I'd like to see how the bullets are being built in action, have you tried adding a left padding in de "ul" element?

Comment: Hi, can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so, this is how i resolved your problem, please enter here: https://embed.plnkr.co/H110p2/

First. Forget about floats, they are nearly deprecated. I removed them from your css. Only in a few cases are necessary, not for this.

Second. Look in the index.html I wrapped every country name in a `<p>` so i could handle them easier in the css.

Third, check the css file, first I cleaned `.translate_ul li` padding and set it to 0. Then I created a handler for the image inside the `<li>` element and also for the `<p>` element. Then I used the property `display: inline-block` in both elements, this tells the navigator that they are aligned one next to other, the property: `vertical-align: middle`, says that I want them align at the middle of each other. Finally I added a small margin to the left of the `<p>` element for aesthetics.

```
.translate_ul li {
  text-align: left;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background-position: 0 -1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.translate_ul li p{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin-left:5px;
}
.translate_ul li img{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  width:16px;
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Asaf, THANK YOU SO MUCH!  It is now working. I still have the bullet dots to the left of the images but I can live with them. Now my list is beautifully aligned!

Answer (score 0):

```
.translate_ul ul {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; // <= YOU NEED TO ADD LEFT PADDING HERE
  list-style: none;
}
```

I Believe the solution is to add left padding to your "ul" element, try that considering the width of the flags.

Comment: Hi Asaf, I tried the suggestion and nothing happened. Then I change: .translate_ul li {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 33px;
  } and this moved the country names right, but they are not aligned with the flags - they seem underneath but now to the right

Comment: I meant to say I tried padding-left: 15px; and other values

Comment: Try adding your code to plunker and post it so y can check it live

Comment: This is the original and how it previously looked: https://www.arrowchat.com/store/app/page-translate

Comment: Sorry plnker? do i upload the entire folder for the application? Sorry I am new to this

Comment: yes https://plnkr.co I'm already working on it, I'll let you know when finished :)

Comment: Is that what you meant?